# How to bind function references inside of a higher order function? Composition over inheritance

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create bind each function reference to a specific animal but it's never referring to the right animal I expect?

I have tried using various .call, .binds, but I am unsure how I'm misusing them.

```
const sleeper = animal => ({
  sleep() {
    animal.energy += 10;
    console.log(`${animal.name} is sleeping! Energy is now ${animal.energy}!`);
  }
});

const eater = animal => ({
  eat() {
    animal.energy += 5;
    console.log(`${animal.name} is eating! Energy is now ${animal.energy}!`);
  }
});

const speaker = animal => ({
  speak() {
    animal.energy -= 3;
    console.log(`${animal.name} has uttered something!`)
  }
})


const Animal = (...args) => {

  return (name, energy = 0) => {
    const animal = {
      name,
      energy,
    }

    // this is where I am confused
    const boundFunctions = args.map(func => {
      return func.bind(animal)()
    })


    return Object.assign(animal, ...boundFunctions)
  }
}

const Monkey = Animal(sleeper, eater)
const Tiger = Animal(sleeper, eater, speaker)

const Reggie = Monkey("Reggie");
const Tony = Tiger('Tony')

Reggie.sleep()
Tony.eat()
```

I'd like each instantiated animal to have a reference to their own name and energy. But it is undefined.

Comment: I don't think this could be called "composition over inheritance", since you're not really using the behaviours as components. They rather are mixed into the instance.

Comment: Btw I think this could be made much simpler if you didn't use functions that take an specific `animal` as an argument. Just write methods that use the `this` keyword which is late-bound (at the call site), so all you need to do is put the method on the animal object.

Comment: Interesting, I read about composition, meaning changing them to be a reflection of what they do, as opposed to what they are. For example, a Tiger being an 'x and y' and another animal being an 'x, y, z, and more'. This was the first way I thought of implementing it.  I'll have to read more about this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to use `bind` here. The behavioural functions just need to be called with the animal as an argument, they return an object with a closure. Use

```
const boundFunctions = args.map(func => func(animal))
```

Comment: Amazing. I knew I was close, but so sure I had to bind the function reference. Thanks for talking me off the ledge.